# DynamoDB - overwrite HashKey with batch operation

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB and I use it to store some information about EC2 instances so I use the instance id as a HashKey.

Once a week, I am running a code which inserts a lot of records into this table:

```
AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB);

// saving records
List<FailedBatch> failedBatch = mapper.batchSave(recordsToSave);
```

I only care about up-to-date information so I would like to overwrite the old record in the DynamoDB if the HashKey that I am trying to insert is already present in the database. However, everytime I try to insert such value, the operation fails (failedBatch) because it cannot handle duplicities.

Is there a way how to achieve this behaviour with DynamoDB or do I have to change the table design?

Comment: Do you have the specific error?  You should be able to replace items with a batch request, but some functionality such as conditional writes is not available when using the batch operation.

Comment: BatchWriteItem is definitely able to overwrite existing items in the table. The error about duplicates sounds like you're including multiple writes for the same hash key in a single batch.

Comment: This contradicts the second answer... could you provide some evidence in documentation to support this statement please? I have not found any.

Comment: "The record already exists in the table" is conspicuously missing from the list of reasons a BatchWriteItem call may be rejected [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html), but it does say the request will be rejected if "You try to perform multiple operations on the same item in the same BatchWriteItem request. For example, you cannot put and delete the same item in the same BatchWriteItem request." It's also pretty easy to verify that overwrites work with a small integration test.

Comment: those are reasons to reject the entire batch. if batch is accepted, certain things may still be failed... which I guess is what we are seeing in this case

Comment: Individual items will only show up as unprocessed because of throttling or temporary unavailability of the partition, and the DynamoDBMapper will [keep on re-sending](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/1.10.8/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.java#L1733) unprocessed items as new batches until all items are successfully written. If it returns a FailedBatch, it's because the entire batch was rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch operations cannot update items. See:

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html

BatchWriteItem cannot update items. To update items, use the UpdateItem API.

What I would do is:

- attempt to do the batch write
- look at failures that come back
- batch get the failed items and batch write them to a temp table
- batch write delete all the items that were failed (already existing)
- batch write the failures again to main table
- purge all items from temp table

As an alternative you can use the UpdateItem api but that's probably going to be slower.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the answer... I was really hoping for some easier solution but I guess this is the only way.

Comment: "Update" in that quote means a partial update of an item (which is what UpdateItem does), as opposed to a total overwrite of the item (which is what PutItem and BatchWriteItem do). The way they have it phrased is not the most clear. :(